Inverse transform before backpropagation
I am computing a GNN, where the target feature of some nodes also serves as an input feature to the other nodes. This means that I not only standardize the features but also think it would be best to standardize the target feature.
However, for the time being, this means, that when computing my training error, I am computing the error between the prediction and the standardized ground truth of the target feature. But for my understanding, computing the loss with the non-standardized ground truth would be much better. However, I am struggling  with how to apply inverse transform before I backpropagate.
My (simplified) code is the following:
def train_my_model():
        
        # Load the data    
        Adjacency_matrix,test_set,training_set = load_data()

        # The other features were previously standardized.
        # In this step I only standardize the target!        
        scaler_target = StandardScaler()
        y_train_scaled = scaler_target.fit_transform(y_train)  
        y_test_scaled = scaler_target.transform(y_test) 

        # Merge the scaled y back onto the data                
        training_set[:, :, 0] = y_train_scaled  
        test_set[:, :, 0] = y_test_scaled  

        # Initiate the model
        my_model = GNN() 
        criterion = nn.L1Loss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(my_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

        # Training the model
        for epoch in range(max_iter):
            for i in range(100):  
                (....)
                    subset_of_training_data = .... # create subset of training_set

                    # Train the model
                    prediction = my_model(subset_of_training_data)

                    # I am assuming that here I should apply inverse_transform.

                    # compute the loss and backpropagate
                    loss = criterion(prediction[:, :], subset_of_training_data[ :, :, 0])
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()      

I am assuming, that I need to both inverse_transform both X_res and subset_of_training_data, right before computing the loss. However, everything I have tried results in detaching and make the backpropagation useless.
I tried converting X_res to an array (but then it is detached). I also tried the following lines of code, but this results in my training error not decreasing anymore.
                 
X_res = scaler_target.inverse_transform(X_res.detach().cpu().numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(X_res.shape)
X_res = torch.tensor(X_res).float().requires_grad_()


I am not sure about the data format, but can't you keep the original version? That is, you will have three parts of data, x, y', and y, where y' is the transformed target. You use the first two as the input to the model while using the last one for computing loss.
